# Convert JSON object into java class object

Tags: java, json, class

I have JSONObject having date field which I want to convert into Class object.

I am using Object Mapper() but while parsing I am getting error.

JSONObject caseDetailsJson = method which returns JSONObject;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setDateFormat(apiDateFormat);

While getting class object :
 ABC abc = mapper.readValue(caseDetailsJson.toJSONString(), ABC.class);

I am getting exception because of date parameter in JSON since date value does not has "" and it takes only starting word.

For example : Date value is :"dateCollected":Fri Jul 07 00:00:00 IST 1989,

but its taking only Fri and not whole date.

Answer (score 0):

The date format does not appear to be standard.

You use `mapper.setDateFormat(apiDateFormat);`. Try using a proper date format that will match your string format.

You did not provide enough details, and code samples would be welcomed for more accurate answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your date value is not double quoted, it is not JSON as specified. Have a look at here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159 or here http://json.org/

I'm afraid you have to tweak your input.